# JSON Structure without Keys

Tags: java, json

I downloaded some information in json format, but it looks different from what I am regularly used to.
The basic structures consists of two objects: an array of arrays without keys and an array of objects with key:value pairs, indicating the "keys" for the first array and their type.

```
{
  "datatable": {
    "data": [
      [
        "2022-04-26",
        118313,
        0,
        "QQQ",
        null,
        "BL6CD96",
        "ARCAVA4600V8",
        "XBUE",
        "INVESCO QQQ TRUST SE1-CEDEAR",
        "Invesco QQQ Trust Series 1",
        "False",
        "False"
      ],
      [
        "2022-04-26",
        56360,
        22669,
        "QQQ",
        "46090E103",
        "BDQYP67",
        "US46090E1038",
        "XNAS",
        "INVESCO QQQ TRUST SERIES 1",
        "Invesco QQQ Trust Series 1",
        "True",
        "False"
      ],
      [
        "2022-04-26",
        44307,
        25533,
        "IBM",
        "459200101",
        "2005973",
        "US4592001014",
        "XNYS",
        "INTL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP",
        "International Business Machines Corp",
        "True",
        "True"
      ]
    ],
    "columns": [{
        "name": "marketdate",
        "type": "Date"
      },
      {
        "name": "seckey",
        "type": "Integer"
      },
      {
        "name": "securityid",
        "type": "Integer"
      },
      {
        "name": "ticker",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "cusip",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "sedol",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "isin",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "mic",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "securityname",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "companyname",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "uslisted",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "innqgi",
        "type": "text"
      }
    ]
  },
  "meta": {
    "next_cursor_id": null
  }
}
```

Result I am trying to achieve:

```
{
  "datatable": {
    "data": [
      [
        "marketdate":"2022-04-26",
        "seckey":118313,
        "securityid":0,
        "ticker":"QQQ",
        "cusip":"null",
        "sedol":"BL6CD96",
        "isin":"ARCAVA4600V8",
        "mic":"XBUE",
        "securityname":"INVESCO QQQ TRUST SE1-CEDEAR",
        "companyname":"Invesco QQQ Trust Series 1",
        "uslisted":"False",
        "innqgi":"False"
      ],
...
  },
  "meta": {
    "next_cursor_id": null
  }
}
```

How can I convert this into a regular key=value JSON OR
How do I parse this in Java so that I have a POJO where the variable names = "colName"?

Thanks a lot!
Nikhil

Comment: Please, post an example (excerpt) of the result

Comment: Which library for parsing json are you using?

Comment: @Chaosfire I use Jackson 2.6.6 for parsing

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky added an example of the result
I am also ok if I can directly parse it into a POJO

Answer (score 1):

You need to map column names from second array to values from first array using indexes. First let's create POJO structure.

```
public class DataObject {

  private LocalDate marketDate;
  private int secKey;
  private int securityId;
  private String ticker;
  private String cusip;
  private String sedol;
  private String isin;
  private String mic;
  private String securityName;
  private String companyName;
  private String uslisted;
  private String innqgi;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Then:

```
public class DataWrapper {

  private List<DataObject> data;

  //getters setters
}
```

Response:

```
public class Response {

  private DataWrapper datatable;

  //getters setters

  //omitting meta
}
```

Then create deserializer to map column names to corresponding values:

```
public class ResponseDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Response> {

  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

  private final Map<String, BiConsumer<JsonNode, DataObject>> map = new HashMap<>();

  public ResponseDeserializer() {
    super(Response.class);
    this.initMap();
  }

  private void initMap() {
    map.put("marketdate", (jsonNode, dataObject) -> dataObject.setMarketDate(LocalDate.parse(jsonNode.asText(), FORMATTER)));
    map.put("seckey", (jsonNode, dataObject) -> dataObject.setSecKey(jsonNode.asInt()));
    map.put("cusip", (jsonNode, dataObject) -> dataObject.setCusip(jsonNode.asText()));
    //do the same for rest
  }

  @Override
  public Response deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    JsonNode root = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
    ArrayNode dataArray = (ArrayNode) root.get("datatable").get("data");
    ArrayNode columnsArray = (ArrayNode) root.get("datatable").get("columns");
    List<DataObject> objects = new ArrayList<>(dataArray.size());
    for (int index = 0; index < dataArray.size(); index++) {
      ArrayNode data = (ArrayNode) dataArray.get(index);
      DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
      for (int dadaIndex = 0; dadaIndex < data.size(); dadaIndex++) {
        JsonNode node = data.get(dadaIndex);
        String columnName = columnsArray.get(dadaIndex).get("name").asText();
        this.map.getOrDefault(columnName, (jsonNode, dataObject1) -> {}).accept(node, dataObject);
      }
      objects.add(dataObject);
    }
    DataWrapper wrapper = new DataWrapper();
    wrapper.setData(objects);
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setDatatable(wrapper);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Here i am using a `Map` to map column name to operation setting the value, but you could do it with reflection as well, for example.

A serializer to parse local date to the same format as in input:

```
public class LocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {

  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

  public LocalDateSerializer() {
    super(LocalDate.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeString(FORMATTER.format(value));
  }
}
```

Register serializers/deserializers and test result:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(Response.class, new ResponseDeserializer());
    module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    Response response = mapper.readValue(inputJson, Response.class);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
    System.out.println(json);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


class HashMapExample {

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> bigHashMap;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = getJsonFromSource();

            // Get datatable object from JSONObject
            JSONObject dataTable = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("datatable");

            if (dataTable != null) {

                // Get JSONArray from JSONObject datatable
                JSONArray data = dataTable.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONArray columns = dataTable.getJSONArray("columns");

                mapToKeyValuePair(data, columns); // Map key to value
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void mapToKeyValuePair(final JSONArray dataArray, final JSONArray columnsArray) {

        // Check for equal lengths
        if ((dataArray != null) && (columnsArray != null)) {

            ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>(); // ArrayList with field names
            ArrayList<String> dataValuesArrays = new ArrayList<>(); // ArrayList with the data values
            ArrayList<HashMap> wholeFinalArray = new ArrayList<>(); // The whole array with key pair value

            // Loop to get a JSONObject with all the column names
            for (int i = 0; i < columnsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectColumn = (JSONObject) columnsArray.get(i); // Get JSONObject with column names
                fieldNames.add(jsonObjectColumn.get("name").toString()); // Get fieldNames from JSONObject above
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray jsonArrayData = (JSONArray) dataArray.get(i); // Get JSONArray with data
                dataValuesArrays.add(jsonArrayData.toString()); // Add the data to an ArrayList
            }

            // Loop through the data values combined arrays
            for (String dataValuesArray : dataValuesArrays) {

                JSONArray singleDataArray = new JSONArray(dataValuesArray); // Get single data array

                for (int a = 0; a < singleDataArray.length(); a++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                    item.put(fieldNames.get(a), singleDataArray.get(a).toString());
                    wholeFinalArray.add(item);
                }
            }
        
            System.out.println(wholeFinalArray);
        }
    }

    private static JSONObject getJsonFromSource() {

        String jsonResponse = "{'datatable':{'data': [['2022-04-26', 118313, 0, 'QQQ', null, " +
            "'BL6CD96', " +
            "'ARCAVA4600V8', 'XBUE', 'INVESCO QQQ TRUST SE1-CEDEAR', 'Invesco QQQ Trust Series 1', 'False', 'False'],['2022-04-26', 56360, 22669, 'QQQ', '46090E103', 'BDQYP67', 'US46090E1038', 'XNAS', 'INVESCO QQQ TRUST SERIES 1', 'Invesco QQQ Trust Series 1', 'True', 'False'],['2022-04-26', 44307, 25533, 'IBM', '459200101', '2005973', 'US4592001014', 'XNYS', 'INTL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP', 'International Business Machines Corp', 'True', 'True']],'columns': [{'name':'marketdate', 'type':'Date'},{'name':'seckey', 'type':'Integer'},{'name':'securityid', 'type':'Integer'},{'name':'ticker', 'type':'text'},{'name':'cusip', 'type':'text'},{'name':'sedol', 'type':'text'},{'name':'isin', 'type':'text'},{'name':'mic', 'type':'text'},{'name':'securityname', 'type':'text'},{'name':'companyname', 'type':'text'},{'name':'uslisted', 'type':'text'},{'name':'innqgi', 'type':'text'}]}, 'meta':{'next_cursor_id':null}}";

        return new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
    }
}
```